# Users can not write to Firebase when they first log in

Tags: swift, firebase

The issue that I am facing is that when the user first signs up for my application (and I see the name added in the authentication on firebase) and attempts to write a post, it does not allow them, it doesn't give an error either. The interesting thing is that when the user leaves the app, deletes the history and relaunches it, the user can make posts and write to the real time database. Doing some testing, I see the same issue and there seems to be errors in the logs:

```
2019-01-18 14:02:32.251806-0500 Jama3aV2[35603:8067503] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C17.1:2][0x10254c2e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-01-18 14:02:32.252321-0500 Jama3aV2[35603:8067503] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C17.1:2][0x10254c2e0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

I tried doing a lot of searches but couldn't get a solution, some people said that this could be an issue with iOS 12, while others said that it was an Xcode issue so I was not sure. The following is the code that creates the post.

```
    @IBAction func handlePostButton(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let image = desciptionImage.image else {return}

        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways){
            currentLocation = locationManager.location
        }

        //Need to specify the area of ryerson.
//        if ((currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < 43.657821 && currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > 43.656258 ) && (currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < -79.380299 && currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > -79.37842 )) {

        self.uploadProfileImage(image, completion: { (url) in
            guard let url = url else {return}
            guard let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile else { return }
            var postID: String!
            //Lets make a reference to the database
            var postref: DatabaseReference!

            //Check which view its coming from
            if self.cityLocationInNewPost?.school == nil {
                postref = Database.database().reference().child("posts/school/\((self.school)!)").childByAutoId()
                postID = "\((postref)!)"
                print("The post ID \(String(describing: postID))")
                postID = postID.replacingOccurrences(of: "https://jama3a-version2.firebaseio.com/posts/school/\((self.school)!)/", with: "")
                print(postID!)
            }else {
                postref = Database.database().reference().child("posts/school/\((self.cityLocationInNewPost?.school)!)").childByAutoId()

            }
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            self.ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)/numberOfPosts")
            self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if let number = snapshot.value as? Int {
                    self.numberOfPosts = number
                }
            }

            //This will assign this post a specific identifier that we can reference it by.
            //This is referencing the place where you write a post
            let postObject = [
                "author":[
                    "uid": userProfile.uid,
                    "photoURL": userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString,
                    "username": userProfile.username,
                    "email": userProfile.email,
                    "numberOfPosts": 0
                ],
                "text": self.textView.text,
                "postphotoURL": url,
                "Status": "\(self.statusOfPost)",
                "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"],
                "location":[
                    "latitude": currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                    "logitude": currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                ],
                "PostID": postID
                ] as [String:Any]

            postref.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: {Error, ref in
                if Error == nil {

                    //This will set the value
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()){
                        if self.cityLocationInNewPost?.school == nil {
                            //This is coming from the subscription need to initialte that view
                            let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let vc = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedIn2ViewController") as! LoggedIn2ViewController
                            vc.school = self.school
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

                        }else {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        //lets set the numberofposts to the variable
                        self.updateNumberOfPosts()
                    }
                }else {
                    print(Error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    self.creatAlert(title: "Error", message: "Error making a Post!")
                }
            })
        })
            //Giving an alert that the post was succesful
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "Your post is successful! Thank you for the contribution", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome!", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
//        }else {
//            self.creatAlert(title: "Cant Make Post!", message: "Cant make post since you are not on the School's campus!")
//            textView.text = ""
//        }
    }
```

and the following to upload the profile picture:

```
func updateNumberOfPosts() {
    //We will need to increment the number of posts
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/profile/\(uid)/numberOfPosts")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if var number = snapshot.value as? Int {
            print(number)
            number = number + 1
            self.ref.setValue(number)
            print(number)
        }
    }
```

Again, the error only occurs when the user first signs up and tries to make a post. This is affecting my production side; I have opened up a case with the support team at Firebase as well.

Comment: Those BoringSSL logs are just a noisy dependency of Firebase - they come in even in an empty project that initializes Firebase. As for your problem, in your second snippet, you're observing a ref that ends in `numberOfPosts`, but I don't see you writing to that ref anywhere.

Comment: numberOfPosts is another function that is used later on, I didn't think it would be necessary to include, its just a function that increments a number

Comment: when there is no `Auth.auth().currentUser` ...the user is not logged in. you probably should not just `return`, but let both functions check the auth-state and login, when required. logging the absent auth might help to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **updateChildValues** instead of setValue?

Using `setValue` overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes. `updateChildValues` on the other hand, allows you to update lower-level child values by specifying a path for the key.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: The issue is not with the number of posts.